# what will be the input type for the KeyClass and ValueClass in case of TextInputFormat in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to know what will be the datatypes for KeyClass and ValueClass if we are using TextInputFormat.

In Ref, from Hadoop the definitive guide 4th edition.

"The input types are controlled via the input format, which we have not explicitly set because we are using the default TextInputFormat."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key would be the line number and it uses `LongWritable` and the value would be `Text`.

```
public class TextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>
```